# Eager Loading "No coercion operator is defined between types" after .NET Core/EF Core 2.0 Upgrade

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

In .NET Core 1.x, we had a method that looked like this:

```cs
public async Task<(PaperRecord Component, PaperPointerRecord Pointer)> GetOneAsync(DbSet<PaperPointerRecord> paperPointerRecords,
                                                                                   int? paperId = null,
                                                                                   long? externalPaperId = null,
                                                                                   Expression<Func<PaperPointerRecord, bool>> filter = null)
{
    var query = filter is null ? paperPointerRecords.AsQueryable() : paperPointerRecords.Where(filter);

    if (paperId.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(_ => _.PaperPointerId == paperId);

    if (externalPaperId.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(_ => _.ExternalId == externalPaperId);

    var record = await query.Include(_ => _.Paper)
                            .ThenInclude(_ => _.PaperColors)
                            .Select(_ => new
                                         {
                                             PaperRecord = _.Paper,
                                             PaperPointerRecord = _
                                         })
                            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    return !(record is null) ? (record.PaperRecord, record.PaperPointerRecord) : throw NewPaperRecordNotFoundException(paperId, externalPaperId);
}
```

This worked great for us. After upgrading the entire project to everything .NET Core 2.0 & EF Core 2.0, the method throws this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred: No coercion operator is defined between types 'PaperPointerRecord' and 'PaperRecord'.

This exception is occuring in this block:

```cs
var record = await query.Include(_ => _.Paper)
                        .ThenInclude(_ => _.PaperColors)
                        .Select(_ => new
                                     {
                                         PaperRecord = _.Paper,
                                         PaperPointerRecord = _
                                     })
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

If I remove the eager loading and make it like so, then the error goes away, but I don't get the intended results either:

```cs
var record = await query.Select(_ => new
                                     {
                                         PaperRecord = _.Paper,
                                         PaperPointerRecord = _
                                     })
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

I've checked the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) for this and I don't see anything being shown there that indicates we are doing something wrong with eager loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` isn't useful in this situation as you are returning a projection and the `Include`s are ignored (read about ignored includes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)).

If by "intended results" you mean you want `record.PaperRecord.Paper` to have a value, simply include it in your projection; EF will wire up the relationship.

```
new
{
    PaperRecord = _.Paper,
    PaperPointerRecord = _,
    PaperColor = _.Paper.PaperColor,
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with your assessment. I did resolve this by basically doing as you suggested. In the end the code is reduced and more straight-forward. What concerned me though was more that it worked fine in 1.x and in 2.0, it took issue with it. In some ways it served to help make things better. But the situation was a bit forced requiring us to go through and rewrite a lot of code.